# Google visualisation chart not displaying

Tags: 2013, google-chart

I did create a google visualization chart in sharepoint 2013 and configured it to one of my sharepoint lists. When the page is loaded, the chart is not displaying, but once I refresh it, the chart is displayed. It might be because delay in loading of js files. Is there a way to overcome this

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue but adding a timeout function works fine me:

```
$.ajax({
    url: weburl,
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    },
    success: function (response) {

        google.charts.load('current', { packages: ["orgchart"] });
        setTimeout(function () {
            google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart(response));
        }, 5000);

    },
    error: function (err) {
        //Handle errors
    }
});

function drawChart(r){
  //to do
}
```